# Minecraft 1.7.10 not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, windows-10

everytime i try loading a world on 1.7.10 i get a code that says java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException im using a windows 10 computer and i cant figure out how to fix it someone help me please